# Finding symmetric pairs in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a complex query to execute on a large PostgreSQL table.  Here is a sample of the data:

[image]

My goal is to fill the column `to_from` with the character `y` or `n`.

Let's take the first row as an example - the value in `start` = 48749 and the value in `end` = 50699.  If another other row in exists *anywhere* in the table where the values are the inverse, i.e., where `end` = 48749 and the value in `start` = 50699, I'd like to fill the column `to_from` of *both rows* with `y`.  If the inverse does not exist, the first row should be filled with with `n`.   The key here is to loop over every row and search for it's inverse in the table.  If an inverse is found, a `y` should be inserted.  However, if there is more than one row that contains an inverse, only the first inverse row should receive an `y`.

I know that I should structure my query along the lines of

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable 
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
AND
WHERE EXISTS
```

But am not sure how to produce the output I am looking for.  Should I create a duplicate table and start from there?  Any guidance on where to start or steps to take?

Here is an example of what the output should look like (if it were 10 rows).  Once a record is used for a pair, it cannot be used for another.

So:

```
> my_table
   ogc_fid track_fid start_gid end_gid to_from
1        1         1       100      82       y
2        2         2        82     100       y
3        3         3       100      82       y
4        4         4       100      32       n
5        5         5        82     100       y
6        6         6        82     100       y
7        7         7        82     100       n
8        8         8       100      82       y
9        9         9        34     100       n
10      10        10        31     100       n
```

Comment: `track_fid` is the primary key

Comment: can you paste your table as text and show how the output should look like? it is also unclear what you mean by *if there is more than one row that contains an inverse, only the first inverse row should receive an y* where as in the beginning you say both the rows should get a `y`.

Comment: What I mean is, `y` should be limited to a pair of inverses.  Let's say (again using the first row as an example), that there are three rows where `end` = 48749  and  `start` = 50699.  Only one of those rows should receive a `y`.  I guess it would the first one of those three found.  Does that make sense?

Comment: is there an order which specifies first 2 records here?

Comment: By the ascending order of `track_fid`- the first one reached

Comment: I still don't get it. There are seven 100/82 and 82/100 records in your table. You mark them all with a 'y', except for record 7 which gets an 'n'. Why? Do you want to end up with exactly one 'n' record per gid combination? If so, what makes you pick record 7; why not record 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 or 8 instead?

Comment: this is because a `y` indicates one commute.   I am assuming a commute is one trip from A-B and a return from B-A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `greatest` and `least` to get the counts of inverse rows. If more than one such row exists, assign `y` to the first such pair, else assign `n`.

```
SELECT ogc_fid,
       track_fid,
       wkb_geo,
       start_gid,
       end_gid,
       CASE
           WHEN count(*) over(partition BY grtst,lst) > 1 THEN 'y'
                --AND row_number() over(partition BY grtst,lst
                                      --ORDER BY track_fid)<=2 THEN 'y'
           WHEN count(*) over(partition BY grtst,lst) = 1 THEN 'n'
       END AS to_from
FROM
  (SELECT ogc_fid,
          track_fid,
          wkb_geo,
          start_gid,
          end_gid,
          greatest(start_gid,end_gid) AS grtst,
          least(start_gid,end_gid) AS lst
   FROM mytable) t
```

Comment: thanks! what is the last character `t` at the end of the query referring to?

Comment: it is an alias for the derived table. you can name it whatever you want excepting the reserved keywords though.

Comment: and the rows in the output `to_from` that are blank are `n` ? there are many blanks

Comment: not `n`. they are `null`s because they don't meet any of the conditions in the `case` expression.

Comment: which means they do not contain an inverse?

Comment: no..they are inverses and not the first 2 records of such pairs

Comment: oh, I see, `null` represents rows that have an inverse but it cannot form a pair

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131857/discussion-between-the-darkside-and-vkp).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131864/discussion-between-the-darkside-and-vkp).

Comment: see the edit..i think this is what you are looking to do based on your example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `row_number()` as well as a `join` to identify the first among the matches:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(t2.new_to_from, 'n') as new_to_from
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by start, end order by start) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t left join
     (select t.*, 'y' as new_to_from,
             row_number() over (partition by start, end order by start) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t2
     on t2.start = t.end and t2.end = t.start and
        t2.seqnum = 1 and t.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: It is a table alias used for a self join.

Comment: I get the error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "end"
LINE 4: ...           row_number() over (partition by start, end order ...`

Comment: and when I replace `start` with `start_gid` and `end` with `end_gid` I get : `ERROR:  column reference "to_from" is ambiguous
LINE 2:        coalesce(t2.to_from, 'n') as to_from`

Answer (score 0):

Number your records per start_gid and end_gid. Then look at gid combinations (100/82 = 82/100) by using `LEAST` and `GREATEST` and see which records don't have a partner (i.e. no other record in the combination with that row number).

```
select
  ogc_fid, track_fid, start_gid, end_gid, to_from,
  case when count(*) over (partition by small_gid, large_gid, rn) = 1 then 'n' else 'y' end
from
(
  select 
    ogc_fid, track_fid, start_gid, end_gid, to_from,
    least(start_gid, end_gid) as small_gid,
    greatest(start_gid, end_gid) as large_gid,
    row_number() over(partition by start_gid, end_gid order by track_fid) as rn
  from mytable
) numbered;
```

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS()` yields a boolean value, which can be used in a `CASE WHEN ...` conditional expression:

---

```
UPDATE mytable t
SET to_from = CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT * FROM mytable x
                          WHERE x.start_gid = t.end_gid
                          AND x.end_gid = t.start_gid )
                        AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM mytable nx
                          WHERE nx.start_gid = t.start_gid
                          AND nx.end_gid = t.end_gid
                          AND nx.ogc_fid > t.ogc_fid -- tie-breaker :: only the first will get a 'y'
                        )
                THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END
        ;
```